# Why is my NSString not reading my .txt file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have the following code to read a .txt file and to put it into a string to use for NSScanner.

```
    NSString *Period1String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period1String" ofType: @"txt"];
    NSString *Period2String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period2String" ofType: @"txt"];
    NSString *Period3String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period3String" ofType: @"txt"];
    NSString *Period4String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period4String" ofType: @"txt"];
    NSString *Period5String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period5String" ofType: @"txt"];

    NSURL *requestTimetableURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dhsb.org/index.phtml?d=201435"];
    NSLog(@"Loaded Timetable");
    NSError *loaderror;
    NSString *page = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestTimetableURL 
                                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                 error:&loaderror];

    [webView loadHTMLString:page baseURL:requestTimetableURL];

    NSString* Period1;

    NSScanner *htmlScanner =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    [htmlScanner scanUpToString:Period1String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner scanString:Period1String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period1];

    period1label.text= Period1;

    NSLog(@"Collected Period 1 Data: %@", Period1);

    NSScanner *htmlScanner2 =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    NSString* Period2;

    [htmlScanner2 scanUpToString:Period2String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner2 scanString:Period2String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner2 scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period2];

    period2label.text= Period2;

    NSLog(@"Collected Period 2 Data: %@", Period2);

    NSScanner *htmlScanner3 =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    NSString* Period3;

    [htmlScanner3 scanUpToString:Period3String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner3 scanString:Period3String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner3 scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period3];

    period3label.text= Period3;

    NSLog(@"Collected Period 3 Data: %@", Period3);

    NSScanner *htmlScanner4 =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    NSString* Period4;

    [htmlScanner4 scanUpToString:Period4String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner4 scanString:Period4String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner4 scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period4];

    period4label.text= Period4;

    NSLog(@"Collected Period 4 Data: %@", Period4);

    NSScanner *htmlScanner5 =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:page];

    NSString* Period5;

    [htmlScanner5 scanUpToString:Period5String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner5 scanString:Period5String intoString:NULL];
    [htmlScanner5 scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&Period5];

    period5label.text = Period5;

    NSLog(@"Collected Period 5 Data: %@", Period5);
```

But, when the button is pressed for all of this to happen, it all the strings (null). Every text file
should be fully working as they have worked for other parts of my app.

Is there a better way I should be doing this or can I improve on this current method to get the results I am looking for?

Thanks

Comment: If I do an NSLog statement for Period1Label, Period2Label, Period3Label, Period4Label and Period5Label - then this si what happens: http://pastie.org/2951134

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 NSString *Period1String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period1String" ofType: @"txt"];
```

This is setting `Period1String` to the path to Period1String.txt rather than the contents of Period1String.txt.

It should be

```
 NSString *Period1String = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Period1String" ofType: @"txt"] usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
```

Substitute in values for encoding and error as appropriate.

Comment: Amazing thank you! Wouldn't have known that otherwise as nothing said on the Internet :D

Comment: Just one more question; why is this not working - it's not picking up that "Period1" contains certain text: http://pastie.org/2951250

Comment: You should really ask that as a new question, but as a quick guess it is that you have to use [Period1 isEqualToString:@"Art] - you can't do string comparisons using == as this compares the object addresses, not the string contents.

Comment: This time it recognises it but says this as an error: http://pastie.org/2951405 - Sorry to ask on here and not as a new question but you seem really good as iOS development so I thought I would ask you :-)